# How can I fix Vuetify v3.4.0 Blackguard date adapter import error?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js, adaptor

When I try to import vuetify date adapter to my project like this:

```
import { VuetifyDateAdapter } from 'vuetify/date/adapters/vuetify'
```

I get this error

**5:24:34 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "vuetify/date/adapters/vuetify" from "src/plugins/vuetify.js". Does the file exist?**

It seems on their website that this adapter can be used in this version.

https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/dates/#format-options

But also i see same error at [play.vuetifyjs.com](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpdjsFqwzAQRH9luxe3UFuF5FScQqCHfkFziHMQ1joIJEtIa5MQ8u+RbAdMTtLO7M684w1jaMXe+2ocCL+xZrLeSKafpgeox1J6P32noXU9S91TWKRJZLpw2WkyCsbSOkVm16CN5wZBPE/F621W5uharCrTGNugPUMkHuZmbb0LDDcI1MEduuAsFIm2yOsr+38g1t31NyXtlfRMYb2dLaGSJ+RsRrGoS07iiwyJG3a56b34I2McHFww6q34yKAzWoLC+yduqk21xfxuqy88PQB1CW4O).

Should I use a different adapter ?

Comment: `VuetifyDateAdapter` is the default date adapter for Vuetify, you don't need to import or use it anywhere, it's already provided for you out of the box.  Although if you _were_ to import it, you're meant to import and use it in `vuetify.js` to configure the Vuetify instance. It's not meant for use in a component like what you've done in your playground link.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this. It works just fine. :)